# Split out similar code to its own code?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have two blocks of code

```
    private async void AorBButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        ResultText.Text = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, App.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

            try
            {
                authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
            }
            catch (MsalException msalex)
            {
                ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
            return;
        }

        if (authResult != null)
        {
            // performs one thing or the other thing
        }
    }
```

So if I click on the A button, it goes through all of the code until it gets to the final if statement and does one set of instructions.
If I press the B button, it goes through all of the same code until it gets to the final if statement but does a different set of instructions.

I think I should be able to break out the code that is exactly the same in both cases and call it from the click events and run the appropriate resultant code.

Just trying to compact the code as much as I can.  I know I can do it in VBA, I just wasn't positive about how to go about it in C#.

Comment: Create one method for button A, another method for button B, a third method with all the code that is the same for both, then make sure either button method calls the common method in the right place. If you ned that common method to execute something different for each button, make sure it has a parameter that can take an appropriate method or lambda to jump into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another async method doing the common stuff and returning the `authResult` as well as a message that you can then assign to `ResultText.Text`. C#7's value tuples come in handy for returning the two results.

```
private async void AorBButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var (authResult, message) = await AquireToken();
    ResultText.Text = message;

    if (authResult != null) {
        // performs one thing or the other thing
    }
}

private async Task<(AuthenticationResult authResult, string message)> AquireToken()
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
    string message = String.Empty;

    try {
        authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, App.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
    } catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex) {
        // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

        try {
            authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
        } catch (MsalException msalex) {
            message = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        message = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
    }
    return (authResult, message);
}
```

It seems cleaner to me to do all the I/O stuff in the Click handlers and to execute pure logic in the `AquireToken` method with no dependencies on TextBoxes or Labels (`ResultText`). This allows you to even extract this logic to its own class.

Comment: Just had to add NuGet "System.ValueTuple" and it worked great!